# Shell script : Year value is not returned

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to get the year of the previous month.
The below code is returning blank year value (i.,e no year value is printed)

```
findPrvYear(){
(
set `date +%m" "%Y`
CURMTHY=$1
CURYRY=$2
if [ $CURMTHY -eq 01 ]
then PRVMTHY=12
     PRVYRY=$(expr $CURYRY - 1)
else PRVMTHY=$(expr $CURMTHY - 1)
     PRVYRY="$CURYRY"
fi
return "$PRVYRY"
)
}

thisMonthY=$(date +%m)
thisYearY=$(date +%y)
retPrvYear=$(findPrvYear $thisMonthY $thisYearY)
echo "valueassigned" $retPrvYear   //This is not printing year value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
return "$PRVYRY"
```

With:

```
echo "$PRVYRY"
```

The return statement sets an exit code.  You don't want that.  You want to provide the string on standard output.

#### Simpler example

Consider this simple function:

```
$ fn() { return 100; }
```

Now let's run it:

```
$ fn
```

It produces no output.  It does however set an exit code:

```
$ echo $?
100
```

Exit codes are limited to 8 bits.  So, you probably don't want to pass back years through them.

By contrast consider which does produce a string on stdout:

```
$ fn() { echo 100; }
$ fn
100
```

That string can be captured, as you want, with command substitution:

```
$ x=$(fn)
$ echo $x
100
```

#### Other issues

This code supplies arguments to the function:

```
retPrvYear=$(findPrvYear $thisMonthY $thisYearY)
```

Due to the `set` statement, thought, the function `findPrvYear` ignores those arguments.

#### Simplification

If you have GNU `date`, then code could be replaced with:

```
retPrvYear=$(date -d '1 month ago' +%Y)
```

(This is not compatible with BSD (OSX) `date`.)